Aura Component not working when called using a formula field (Text) whereas working when I place the component on the page layout
I have a simple Aura component that is working when I place the Aura component on the page layout while it does not work when I have the component url accessible.
The component is as follows:
<!--UpdateUserDetails.cmp-->
<aura:component  implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable"
        access="global">
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
        <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.reInit}" />
        <aura:attribute type="String" name="recordId" />
        <aura:html tag="style">
            input[name=password] {
            -webkit-text-security: disc;
            -moz-webkit-text-security: disc;
            -moz-text-security: disc;
            }
    
            input[name="password"] {
            -webkit-text-security: disc;
            -moz-webkit-text-security: disc;
            -moz-text-security: disc;
            }
        </aura:html>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </aura:component>

In addition to that, I have also added the design file as below:
<design:component>
    <design:supportedFormFactors>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Small"/>
    </design:supportedFormFactors>
</design:component>

The formula fields is as follows:

HYPERLINK("/lightning/cmp/c__UpdateUserDetail?c__recordId="+Id,
IMAGE("https://ability-platform-3597--sb1.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0151e0000001xOe&oid=00D1e0000001Abv&lastMod=1700901243000",
""), "_self")
The formula field or button looks like this:


I get the below error when I click on the above formula to get that navigated to the aura component:

